# How could a prisoner get lessons to read, write and do mathematics in jail, while innocent people didn't get the basic knowledge in 18th-19th century?

Tags: social-history

I am currently reading *Les Miserables* manga version ( Which takes place in France, as I recall). In the picture below, the main character has just got his freedom from *Toulon* Jail. The officer said that,

> You must've learned, reading, writing and arithmetic at the prisoner's school

Why did people get these lessons when they were in jail? Why didn't they get this basic knowledge, like writing and reading, when they are just a innocent person? Is this a result of some of the social hierarchy in France?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagne_of_Toulon & https://www.mtholyoke.edu/courses/rschwart/hist255-s01/thenardier/theresa/education.html

Comment: @Bookeater You should post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a history question; it sounds more political in nature. What is it you want to know?  If you want someone to articulate French penal policy in the 18th century, that would make sense.  But the question is phrased in a way that evokes a desire to share outrage at some situation - [help] discourages that.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: It's "enough" of a history question. It was cast as "how," rather than "why." And the answer had to do with prison reform, which is historical.

Comment: @user2448131 the links are just a starting point as they are unsubstantiated. I lacked the time at that point to dig up better. Never mind though an answer is in place.

Comment: This question is not about history but about fiction.

Comment: @Alex: One can reasonably ask if certain things portrayed in a work of fiction are historically accurate (although the question should be very narrow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prisoners were put to work at prisons such as the [Bagne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagne_of_Toulon) in Toulon. Nearly all jobs required "training," and some jobs required teaching prisoners to read and write.

Prison guards found that "working" prisoners were more docile, and they also helped earn their keep.

The period from 1820-1840 was a time of [prison reform](https://www.mtholyoke.edu/courses/rschwart/hist255-s01/thenardier/theresa/reform.html)(shorter sentences, less use of the death penalty, etc. and one of the reforms was education of prisoners so they could earn their livings after being released.